# Printing objects from a JSON file to the console in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I have got a bit of a basic question, but since I'm still a student I can't seem to figure it out.

I have got the following method:

```
getMenus: function () {
   var self=this;
   $.getJSON('../data/voordeelmenus.json',function(data){
      self.menus=$.map(data, function(item, i){
         return new Menu(item.id,item.naam,item.type,item.omschrijving,item.samenstelling,item.prijs);    
     });
      self.menusToHtml(); 
   });
```

The method should (if my code is correct) get menus from a JSON file and make objects of them using the Menu constructor. The objects get stored in the menus array. As you can see I then call to menusToHtml method, but I actually want to test if the objects got stored in the array by printing them out in the console first. I have tried doing this by writing console.log(self.menus) but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Where were you adding the console line?

Comment: If you're doing live debugging of a web page, just set a breakpoint on the `self.menusToHtml()` line and see what `self.menus` is set to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try JSON.stringify on the object first. That should work.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(self.menus));
```

Comment: *"Try stringifying the json first."*: Don't use the term "JSON" to refer to JavaScript objects. What you are doing is converting a *JavaScript object* **to** JSON.